# What is the correct length of time in which a landlord must provide rent increase notices in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, rental-property

The following GOV UK page states that tenants must be notified of rent increases at least 6 months prior to the increase. What I'm failing to understand from this is if that includes the tenancy renewal or does this mean that a landlord is capable of increasing rent at renewal at any time.

For example, if the years fixed term renewal is only 1 month away, does the landlord have the right to increase the rent now for the renewal date, or should the tenants be notified exactly half way through the term?

https://www.gov.uk/private-renting/rent-increases

Answer (score 2):

The link says that 6 months notices are required where you have a yearly tenancy. That is, you pay rent once per year.

If you have a lease that lasts one year but you are required to pay rent monthly or weekly, you **don't** have a yearly tenancy - you have a fixed term one that lasts for a year. The notice period for a rent increase is one months notice.

However, if the lease has a different procedure (e.g. automatic indexing) they have given you the notice *in the lease*.